# get values from unicode variable type on python

Tags: python, unicode

Im trying to get the value (18000) on this unicode variable type on python.
here is the variable :

```
test=  '\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t18 000\t\t\t\t\t\t\xa0\u20ac\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
```

how can I get the 18000.

Im trying to do an url decode()  but I have this error :

> exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters
>   in position 25-26: ordinal not in range(128).

can I have help please.

Comment: That's not urlencoded.... why would you try to url decode it?

Comment: `test.split('\t')[12]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a unicode string with a lot of whitespace and the [U+20AC EURO SIGN](http://codepoints.net/U+20ac) character in it; you'll have to remove these to get your number out:

```
test = test.strip(u' \t\n\r\xa0\u20ac')
```

This removes all newlines, carriage returns, tabs, spaces, no-break spaces (the U+00A0 character) and the U+20AC character from the start and end of your string:

```
>>> test = u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t18 000\t\t\t\t\t\t\xa0\u20ac\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
>>> test.strip(u' \t\n\r\xa0\u20ac')
u'18 000'
```

This still has whitespace in it, of course, so you need to remove that too to get the number:

```
>>> int(test.strip(u' \t\n\r\xa0\u20ac').replace(' ', ''))
18000
```